# YII2 crypt function that did work has stopped

Tags: php, yii2, crypt, yii2-model

I have a page in my site that allows the user to change there password but as part of the form they have to enter the old password.  In the model I have verification to check the old password entered on the form matches the one in the database

```
    public function oldPasswordCheck($attribute, $params)
    {
        $old_password = $this->attributes['password'];
        if (crypt($this->old_password, $old_password) != $old_password)
        {
            $this->addError('old_password', 'This is not the old password');
        }
    }
```

This worked until recently but for some reason now, if you enter the correct old password, it still tells you they didn't match.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why you don't use  password_hash() ? From php manual Use of password_hash() is encouraged.

Comment: Unfortunately, I had to use this, as the users are from a legacy APP and in the app, they do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Some possible answers:

### 1) Your `salt` parameter

Php crypt() function uses two parameters: `crypt ( string $str [, string $salt ] )`. It seems that you are using the password as salt, which is a very bad practice. Is that so or are you just confusing the `salt` parameter? I would also recommend to always compare passwords with php [hash_equals()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-equals.php), because crypt() is vulnerable to [timing attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack).

### 2) changes in your server configuration

What type of hash your php configuration use to crypt/decrypt strings?:

On systems where the crypt() function supports multiple hash types, the following constants are set to 0 or 1 depending on whether the given type is available:   `CRYPT_STD_DES,  CRYPT_EXT_DES,  CRYPT_MD5,  CRYPT_BLOWFISH,  CRYPT_SHA256 and  CRYPT_SHA512`. If you changed recently your server configuration, some of that could not be available anymore. Check it with `phpinfo()`

## A recommendation

You are working with a framework, and Yii like every framework has its own class to crypt and decrypt strings. Take a look at [yii security class](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-security). It will make your life easier.